# Is there a way to add/remove entries from the browser cache?

Tags: javascript, browser, browser-cache

Scenario:

1. A user searches for all tags starting with the word `test`.
2. The server returns `["test1", "test2", "test3"]`, with a `Cache-Control: max-age=86400` (1 day or some other suitably large value).
3. The user adds a new tag: `test4`.
4. The user repeats the search from step 1. The browser returns the cached value from step 2.

Is it possible to update the browser cache in step 3 to do one of the following?

- Update the cached response to include `test4`, or
- Invalid the cache from step 1 immediately.

Is there some sort of Javascript API that lets one interact with the browser cache? I am using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) for all requests.

Comment: There is [`Cache`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache).

Comment: @SebastianSimon This seems to allow me to create my own cache object but doesn't let me manipulate the cache used by the Fetch API. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution would be to use a service worker to intercept all those requests and rewrite responses on the fly. This is probably doable via https://stackoverflow.com/a/42846899/72478 and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/delete

You would always remove the cache header from the server responses, so the browser would never cache them in the regular page cache (that you don't fully control), but cache them in the service worker "Cache Storage". Then the service worker would have full control of what response it would return to the client.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is at step 4 to issue the XHR request and also add a parameter which will make the request unique (new) to the browser. For example `?whatever`.

If the only one affecting the server state is that single user, then JavaScript can keep track of when they affect the state in order to start using a new "cache buster" parameter.

If, on the other hand, the server state can be updated by anyone, then your only (easy) solution is to always keep requesting the server state with a new parameter. Using the current timestamp for that (e.g `?1568952442135`) usually works well.

This, of course, doesn't do what exactly you asked, but it solves the problem of stale data on the client.

Comment: Right, this isn't what I'm after. I only want to bust the cache if step 3 occurs. Your approach invalidates the cache even if the value was never updated.

Comment: My approach doesn't invalidate the cache, but rather requests a new URL. The browser will keep accumulating cached responses for those URLs.

On step 3 you have full control over whether you will request the URL with a new "cache buster" parameter or not.

Comment: I think there is a typo in your last comment. Only step 4 reads from the server, not step 3. What I don't like about this approach is that it requires me to pass a signal from every place that updates the value to every place that might query it. This makes the code harder to maintain but yes, it will work. A cleaner way to achieve this without using random query parameters is using the `cache` parameter of the Fetch API.